# git : how to create a merge with a known outcome

Tags: git, merge, commit

I'm creating a potted project history in git from a series of zip snapshots taken during the project's early development. We know we (me & him) have some cases where we diverged from a base point A, then merged our two versions B & C, back into an agreed update of version D. Typically we used Beyond Compare, and in a few places we updated the code to resolve conflicts.

So I can create A--B on branch 'his', and and A--C on branch 'mine' without any problems. I'm just unsure how I would best create a `merge commit` that has the known outcome of D. I can easily set up the index/staging area with D waiting in it, direct from the zip file.

What's the best command(s) to create the [two parent commit] merge with pre-defined result? For the purpose of this case, 'his' is considered the primary parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply doing a:

```
git merge --no-commit ...
```

followed by simply squashing everything with your known outcome and committing should work.

Comment: It's the "simply squashing everything with your known outcome and committing" bit that I'm unclear on. I'm more used to 'squashing' from a rebase setting.

Comment: That part is the simplest: just unpack your version `D` snapshot on top of your working directory.

Comment: I personally do not like `add -A`. I would recommend using `git add -i` - less chances of accidentally starting to tracking stuff you did not intend to. But in this situation, it `-A` could be ok I guess.

Comment: Cheers. The tricky bit was appreciating when/how git created the 'this commit has two parents' info.